# Problem of executing python script on C# through pyinstaller

Tags: c#, python, pyinstaller

When i run the .exe, it occurred the error.
Does anybody know how to fix it?

> Failed to execute script prediction
>   d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:489: 
>   MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
>     exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "ggcnn1\prediction.py", line 3, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "ggcnn1\func.py", line 4, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "ggcnn1\grasp1.py", line 5, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "site-packages\skimage__init__.py", line 127, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "site-packages\skimage\util__init__.py", line 6, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "site-packages\skimage\util\apply_parallel.py", line 8, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "site-packages\dask__init__.py", line 1, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "site-packages\dask\config.py", line 532, in
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\YKCHEN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI165282\dask\dask.yaml'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution worked for me:

Create a hooks directory:

```
mkdir hooks
```

Create `hook-dask.py` file in ./hooks directory with the following codes:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules, collect_data_files

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('dask')
datas = collect_data_files('dask', subdir=None, include_py_files=True)
```

Create `hook-dask-core.py` file in ./hooks directory with the following codes:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules, collect_data_files

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('dask-core')
datas = collect_data_files('dask-core', subdir=None, include_py_files=True)
```

Run pyinstaller via:

```
pyinstaller -F --noupx --log-level=WARN --additional-hooks-dir=hooks --onefile main.py
```